# How much free storage should we maintain so that iOS can work properly?

Tags: iphone, ios

It was strange that yesterday, the iPhone worked really slowly. The screen can freeze for a few seconds. It was like the Processor or the graphics chip went bad or something.

It was like that when playing Pokemon Go, or just using iOS and the Settings as well, and it was the same even when I restarted the iPhone and used the Settings app -- it was really slow.

And I checked the free storage left, and it was 1.9GB.  So I thought it should be plenty. In the past I have 500MB left and iOS was running all fine.

But this time, it is the iPhone 6 Plus, with 128GB storage, and 1GB of RAM, as opposed to in the past, when my iPhone 5 was just 16GB and it was common to have just 2GB free remaining.

And turning off the App Refresh and restarting the iPhone didn't help either.

So I deleted some big apps like Angry Birds and PvZ 2, which I play on the iPad instead of the iPhone anyway. And when it was 3GB, everything ran smoothly.

And since then, I uploaded some photos to Google Photos and freed up about 2GB of space last night, and made the free space about 5GB, and everything was running really well.

So 1.9GB seemed like not enough and 3GB was enough... what is the amount of free storage that should be kept for iOS itself to work properly?

Comment: If you put the device in airplane mode, then restart - how does iOS perform before you launch any apps? Is storage being pruned after the reboot or is free space maintained at that point? Basically, if apps create files, iOS needs to purge others so eliminating that cycle will be needed to diagnose your setup.

Comment: I put on airplane mode and no app refresh, and it was really slow and freezing at times too (without running any app besides Settings)

Comment: Doesn't matter what app refresh is if there is no network. Slow and freezing in that situation indicate a need to restore iOS and test. Could be hardware - likely software corruption. Once you've figured that - restore from backup.

Comment: after I freed up the storage to be about 3GB, then everything worked well... so are you saying the problem might still exist? For example, some stale memory that is occupying the system for 1.9GB and Settings said it is free but it is not?

Comment: I think you are confusing storage space with RAM. Unless you are specifically getting error messages about storage being full, I don't think free space is the cause of your issues.

Comment: I dealt with Apple II's 48kb RAM in the past, back in 1982... were you even born yet? You know if the RAM is full or near full, some data is swapped into the storage and if storage is near full or not enough, then it is a problem for the whole system